# Disable Multi-Touch on separate Entry Fields in Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, multi-touch

I have 3 Entry Fields one after the other. We are using Custom Entry Renderer for the same.

Problem is :

How to prevent the user from tapping on two entry fields together using two different fingers at the same time.

When we try to do this, both these Entry Fields become active and are on focus.

So how to prevent this type of multi-touch on diff entry fields in Xamarin Forms (for iOS)

Answer (score 0):

You could custom a [ContentPage renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage) and then set [UIView.MultipleTouchEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiview.multipletouchenabled?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(UIKit.UIView.MultipleTouchEnabled);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Xamarin.iOS,Version%253Dv1.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) be false to check whether it works.

For example:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace XamrinTemp.iOS
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            View.MultipleTouchEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```